# ¿como hago convertir codigo c# a javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#

Tengo un problema al momento de para esto a javascript

```
 var rubros = string.Empty;
  foreach (var graf in Model.Grafico.Where(graf > rubros.Contains(graf.Rubro)))
   {
    rubros += "'" + graf.Rubro + "',";
   }
```

Comment: La única manera (fuera de casos muy puntuales) de convertir código de un lenguaje a otro, es hacerlo manualmente. En tu caso, lo único específico del lenguaje sería la palabra reservada `var`, la manera de definir un string vacío (`string.Empty`) y el bucle `foreach`, te sugiero que busques las alternativas de estos 3 puntos en la documentación de JS, y podrás hacer la conversión perfectamente!

Comment: Javascript no tiene Where() tampoco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar el método `filter()` en lugar del Where de Linq, el equivalente al método Contains() en javascript es el método `includes()`, Espero que esto te ayude.